# What is the best practice for maintain users? aspnet_Users or create new user table

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, database, asp.net-membership

I installed the `database` `asp.net` `Membership` but I want to ask what is best practice here should I use the `aspnet_Users` table as a main table for Website user or should create new user table  to store the website users login information and password ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to  my understanding aspnet_Users tables are the easiest and best option if you already not having tables for user management

Answer (score 1):

The generated aspnet_Users table gives you a quick out-of-the-box option, and you can also use it across multiple applications. I have used this before and it has served me well.

Answer (score 1):

I have never used the aspnet_Users table even **once** in my entire career as a software developer, senior software developer and now present software architect.  I think that pretty much sums this up.

Comment: I'm curious, because I haven't looked much at it, but why haven't you used it? Is it implemented badly?

Comment: Never used because there's something wrong with using it, or just never used because not using it is also a valid approach?

Comment: Never because first I hate the default schema to start with, 2nd it's never sufficient for any real world application I've ever worked on.

Answer (score 0):

To me using `asp.net` `membership` provider is a easier and safer way. And it contains in build method that can use. If we need to [Implement a Custom Membership User](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms366730.aspx) it also possible.